# Kubernetes network policy deny-all policy not blocking basic communication

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am running a GKE cluster version 1.17.13-gke.1400.

I have applied the following network policy in my cluster -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Which should block all communication to or from pods on the default namespace.
However, it does not. As is evident from this test -

```
$ kubectl run p1 -it  --image google/cloud-sdk
root@p1:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=1.14 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=1.21 ms
^C
root@p1:/# curl www.google.com 
<!doctype html><html itemscope=" ...
```

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-and-all-egress-traffic), seems like this application should be pretty straight forward.
Any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong, or tips for further troubleshooting, will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Nimrod,

Comment: Which network plugin is your Kubernetes cluster using? That means, does your cluster have the enforcement of network policies enabled at all? See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy#step_1_create_a_cluster

Comment: If so, please check the namespace you are using for your run command. Maybe you are pointing to a different one than default where your network policy is deployed for.

Comment: @AndreasJägle you're right. The issue is that the cluster (also) has windows nodes. And GKE doesn't support network policies with windows nodes.

Comment: @AndreasJägle as you were the founder of the underlying issue, provide your comment as an answer for better visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @DawidKruk. I added my questions to look at as an answer to this question, so that future seekers might find some inspiration without reading these comments. Glad this was already helpful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Network Policies to take effect, your cluster needs to run a network plugin which also enforces them. [Project Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/) or [Cilium](https://cilium.io/) are plugins that do so. This is not the default when creating a cluster!

So first, you should check if your cluster is set up accordingly as described in the [Google Cloud Network Policies docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy#step_1_create_a_cluster). This is somehow abstracted away behind the `--enable-network-policy` flag.

If it is enabled, you should see some calico pods in the `kube-system` namespace.

`kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system`

If there is a plugin in place which enforces network policies, you need to make sure to have deployed the network policy in the desired namespace - and check if your test using `kubectl run` is executed in that namespace, too. You might have some other namespace configured in your kube context and not hit the default namespace with your command.

Answer (score 0):

To install Calico using manifests

Apply the Calico manifests to your cluster. These manifests create a DaemonSet in the kube-system namespace.

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/master/config/master/calico-operator.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/master/config/master/calico-crs.yaml

View the resources in the kube-system namespace.

kubectl get daemonset calico-node --namespace kube-system
Output

The values in the DESIRED and READY columns should match. The values returned for you are different than the values in the following output.

NAME          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
calico-node   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   26m